# pgBouncer - multiple servers with same username but different password

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pgbouncer

I have an active pgBouncer setup with one PostgreSQL server.

We are planning to add one more PostgreSQL server to the same pgBouncer. But the problem is that both databases servers have the same username, but with different passwords.

Server1:

- user: admin
- password: admin123

Server2:

- user: admin
- password: admin@213

This feature is already requested [here](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/233), can someone help me with any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good workaround at the link in your question.

Another thing you can try is to use `auth_user` and `auth_query` with pgBouncer so that it fetches the password from the respective database. I am not sure if that works or if pgBouncer caches the password for each user.

Comment: In that Github link, Im not sure how to do that, any idea?

Comment: This maps two different user names to the same user on different databases. So when you want to connect to `admin` on the first database, you use user `admin1`, and a different name for the other database.

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pgbouncer-authentication-made-easy/ -- Is this the one explained in the answer?

Comment: Yes, that is my idea. You can try if it works.

Comment: Sure, thank you so much